# Negation operation in TCL

Tags: boolean, tcl, negation

I have not managed to find out how to negate booleans in TCL...
I tried:

```
set x true
puts !$x   #prints '!true'
puts ![$x] #prints !
puts [!$x] #prints no event matches "true"
puts !{$x} #prints !{true}
puts {!$x} #prints !$x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logical 'not' is an arithmetic operator, so you need `expr`

```
% set x true
true
% puts [expr {!$x}]
0
% puts [expr {!!$x}]
1
```